# Tricky volume of revolution

Tags: problem-solving, volume

So I was trying to find the volume, but I'm always getting wrong answer.
$$x=-y^2+6y$$
and the y-axis to rotate about is $y=-7$.

$$V = \pi*\int_0^6 (-y^2+6y)^2-49 \;dy$$

But answer doesn't much? Where am I wrong?

Comment: Did you draw a picture with a sample element of area that sweeps out a volume element? What is the region you're rotating? You've only given a curve. Is it the area enclosed by the curve and some line or some axis? If you are rotating the region around the horizontal line y=-7, a slice of thickness dy will sweep out a cylindrical shell. Your integral looks more like a calculation that sums washer-like shapes. Also, $(-y^2+6y)^2$ is less than 49 for $y$-values between 0 and 6, so you are integrating something negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cross-section of this volume is a ring centered about $y=-7$.  The ring is defined by the curves $y=f_{\pm}(x)$, where

$$f_{\pm}(x) = 3 \pm \sqrt{9-x} $$

about $y=-7$.  The volume is then the sum of all the rings over $x$, which goes from $0$ to $9$:

$$V = \pi \int_0^9 dx [(7+f_+(x))^2 - (7+f_-(x))^2]$$

With a little algebra, you can show that this is

$$V = 40 \pi \int_0^9 dx \: \sqrt{9-x} = 720 \pi$$

**EDIT**

Here is a picture of the situation, for what it's worth:

[image]

Comment: ah, that was so simple :)  I didn't think about changing f(y)=x to y=f(x) form

Comment: @castt, do you want another method (using shell method)?

Comment: @castt, I already had posted my answer.

Comment: @castt: yes, if you want to use rings, then we integrate over $x$, so we have to solve for $y$ as a function of $x$.  The way it works out in this problem is that there are two branches of $y$, each of which is a boundary of the ring.  As mentioned in the comments, it is crucial that you draw a useful picture of the situation so that it guides you on setting up the integral.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, it is definitely tricky. The region we are rotating has not been completely described. I take it that it is the part of the region which is simultaneously inside the parabola and inside the first quadrant.  Drawing a picture is essential.

One can use slicing or cylindrical shells. We will use slicing, since that's what you attempted. Then we need to integrate with respect to $x$. Note that $x$ goes from $0$ to $9$, because the vertex of the parabola is at $(9,3)$. (It is $y=3$ because that's halfway between the roots).

We will need to solve the equation $y^2-6y+x=0$. We get $y=3\pm \sqrt{9-x}$. These are, respectively, the equations of the top half and the bottom half of the parabola.

The distance from the top point $3+\sqrt{9-x}$ to $-7$ is $10+\sqrt{9-x}$. The distance from the bottom point $3-\sqrt{9-x}$ to $-7$ is $10-\sqrt{9-x}$. So our volume is
$$\pi\int_0^9 \left[(10+\sqrt{9-x})^2-(10-\sqrt{9-x})^2\right]\,dx.$$
Before integrating, square and simplify. Lots of stuff disappears, and we end up with
$$\pi\int_0^9 40\sqrt{9-x}\,dx.$$
The integration of $\sqrt{9-x}$ is easy. An antiderivative is $-\frac{2}{3}(9-x)^{3/2}$. Thus the volume is $(\pi)(40)\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)(27)$.

Answer (score 0):

Choose a rectangular horizontal strip within the region. The dimension of this chosen strip is $(-y^2+6y)dy$. The distance of this strip from the axis of rotation (which is the line $y=-7$) is given by $y+7$. Hence, the desired volume is $$V=\int_{0}^{6}2\pi(y+7)\cdot (-y^2+6y)dy=720\pi.$$

Comment: you can use this http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sin+x+dx+from+x%3D0+to+pi&lk=3 to evaluate the definite integral.